# 32 bit Image Format32bppArgb seems black in picturebox: C# form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am loading 32 bit TIFF image with pixel format Format32bppArgb in picture box but the image appears to be only black. I am using form based application in VS2010.

`PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(filename);`

Comment: Might it be a multipage image? Can you post a link to anexample?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve problem using libtif library.

1) Read Image using libtif library

2) Extract pixels into a bytearray or memorystream

3) Construct a new image from bytearray and display in picturebox